# Can async tasks be queued

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I would like to have a similar code to the following:

```
async def func(user_response):
 #does_something

while condition:
 #waits for a response from the user
 #await func(response from user)
```

However, I want it to wait for another response from the user while the function is executing.

I have tried:

```
async def func(user_response):
 #does_something

while condition:
 #waits for a response from the user
 #asyncio.create_task(response from user)
```

However, the problem i have found is that if the user responds twice, both functions will be carried out at the same time (when i was them to essentially be queued).

Answer (score 0):

> Can async tasks be queued

Yes, and you can use `asyncio.Queue` for that purpose:

```
async def func(user_response):
    #does_something

async def worker(queue):
    while True:
        user_response = await queue.get()
        await func(user_response)

async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    # spawn the worker in the "background"
    asyncio.create_task(worker(queue))
    while condition:
        #waits for a response from the user
        # enqueue the response to be handled by the worker
        await queue.put(user_response)
```